# Ну получается использовать две команды с кнопками

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Делаю бота для DISCORD с библиотекой disnake.
Сделала команду, которая будет как информационная доска с кнопками, но при участии в коде второго такого же кода, одна работает - другая нет, даже если другая будет на одном сервере. А если их три, то работает только последняя из них.

```
@bot.command()
async def основное(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.id != YOUR_CHANNEL_ID: 
        return
    embed = disnake.Embed(title="-", colour=0x6b0000, description="-"). set_image(url="-").set_footer(text=f"-")

    view = ui.View()
    view.add_item(ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.secondary, label="-", custom_id="button5"))
    view.add_item(ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.secondary, label="❗❗-❗❗", custom_id="button6"))
    view.add_item(ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.link, label="❤️-❤️", url="-"))

    await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)

@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    if interaction.component.custom_id == "button5":
        embed = disnake.Embed(title="-", colour=0x6b0000, description="⁠-")
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
    elif interaction.component.custom_id == "button6":
      embed1 = disnake.Embed(title="-", colour=0x6b0000, description="-")
      embed2 = disnake.Embed(title="-", colour=0x6b0000, description="-")
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed1, ephemeral=True)
        await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed2, ephemeral=True)
pass
```

Это только один, в другом кнопки button4, button3.
Как сделать чтобы работали две команды в коде?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите и что не получается. Либо чуть подробней изложите свою мысль и пример ошибки, либо напишите мне в DS: qrts

Comment: Проблема в том, что мой код в одиночку хорошо работает и как надо: Вызываю команду > появляется блок Embed с кнопками.
Но когда добавляю вторую такую же команду с другим названием, то первая перестает работать и при нажатии на кнопку "Ошибка взаимодействия"(т.е. работает только последняя команда с кнопками), в коносоли ошибок нету.

Comment: Добавьте меня в Discord, мне будет проще понять по скриншотам или готовому коду. (пришлите свой ник как отправите заявку)

Comment: отправила вам заявку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что использовались две функции с одинаковыми названиями:

```
@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    <...>

@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    <...>
```

Достаточно было пронумеровать их:

```
@bot.event
async def on_button_click_1(interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    <...>

@bot.event
async def on_button_click_2(interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    <...>
```